# MS Access: How to run a query on button click on form?

Tags: ms-access-2016

I need to update linked table in MS Access. So I need button on form to click to run a query.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, however, if you don't like using embedded macros then the first answer is what you want to use.  Like me, I like using VBA Code to do everything in my access database.  It makes the Database run faster and a lot more smoother I believe.  But, for those of you who are not into programming in VBA Code using the Create Query Wizard is the smart way to go and does the exact same thing visually, you just don't have to program it in the database...

Answer (score 1):

1. Create button on form.
2. In "Property sheet > Event tab" > On Click > [Event Procedure]
3. Add this code

   Private Sub myButton_Click()
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "myQuery"
   End Sub

And test if works.
Have a good one today :)

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.
From Command Button Wizard, select Run Query from Miscellaneous Ctegories.

[image]